# Why can’t I fill out this field?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, python-webbrowser

so I use Python Selenium Webdriver and I am stuck at filling out that credit card field... I tried many things but nothing worked...
This is my actual code, but it doesn’t work.

How can I fill it out? ([Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWAk.png))<—— Console insight

```
inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("encryptedCardNumber")
            )
            inputCC.send_keys("1111222233334444")
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWAk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of that HTML you will see that input tag is within an `</iframe>.`  You need to switch to that first.  I can't see the iFrame details but something like this....

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='xyz']")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Obviously fill out the Xpath with the correct information above

Then your code...

```
inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("encryptedCardNumber")
            )
            inputCC.send_keys("1111222233334444")
```

Then to switch back to the default content...

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find that iFrame name? It’s the checkout from Footlocker ( DE )

Comment: I can't see it myself without going through the checkout process.  Just get to that HTML page you show in your OP and scroll up a little bit to the top of the iframe tag.  From there you just target it like any other element you would find using selenium...find it by ID, Name, CSS, Xpath or whatever seems to work.  I can't tell since I can't see it